# Create an SEO friendly url in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, seo

I have a scenario to create an SEO friendly URL in Code-igniter.

http://example.com/en/motors/used-car-for-sale/audi?sub_categories3=36

I want to create an SEO friendly url and remove the portion **?sub_categories3=36** from the url. The subcategory id 36 will be the 'A4'(Audi A4 car model).
So the url should be *http://example.com/en/motors/used-car-for-sale/audi/a4* .

The sub_categories3 will be the id of each type under main category.

How can i do it?I found lot of articles to it.Please suggest me a best way to find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362460/codeigniter-seo-friendly-urls?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Pass all /motors requests to the correct controller with ('motors/(:any)') = 'myController/myFunction';

Get the second part of the url and pass it to a model that requests an article with that URL. Use the 'URL' helper for this.

Return data back to the controller and to your view.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Could you please elaborate it?.I am new to code-igniter.